# SSIS Package Failing after update to SQL Server 2012 SP2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis, sql-server-2012

I have a package which was running fine on SQL Server 2012 before an update to SQL Server 2012 SP2.  The Package is now crashing on a derived column step where a bunch of type casts like:

```
(DT_NTEXT)"\" " + (DT_NTEXT)@[User::phantomScriptLoc] + (DT_NTEXT)"getautomatedtable.js " + (DT_NTEXT)"--ignore-ssl-errors=yes -user \"" + (DT_NTEXT)Username + (DT_NTEXT)"\" -pass \"" + (DT_NTEXT)Password + (DT_NTEXT)"\" -url \"" + (DT_NTEXT)@[User::gatewayWebLoc] + (DT_NTEXT)"\" -module \"/" + (DT_NTEXT)module_name + (DT_NTEXT)"/index.cfm\" -reportpage \"" + (DT_NTEXT)report_name + (DT_NTEXT)"\" -deptid \"" + (DT_NTEXT)cast_deptid + (DT_NTEXT)"\" -reportname \"" + (DT_NTEXT)report_title + (DT_NTEXT)"\" -outfile \"" + (DT_NTEXT)@[User::storeReportsLoc] + (DT_NTEXT)filename + (DT_NTEXT)"\" -format \"" + (DT_NTEXT)RTRIM(AutoRpt_FileFmt_Txt) + (DT_NTEXT)"\" -querystring \"" + (DT_NTEXT)queryString + (DT_NTEXT)"&debugMode=1\"\""
```

No error message is produced but it causes SQLDUMPER.EXE to be called and a dump file is created
Any one else had issues since an upgrade to SQL Server 2012 SP2?

EDIT:  This has been submitted as a bug to Microsoft as others on Microsoft connect have reported the same issue since upgrading to SQL Server 2012 SP2

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid expression, am I misreading that? I have access to 2012 SP1 with assorted CUs and I can patch something to sp2 to test but I'd like to get a solid reproduction set up. Also, could you edit your question to include the exact error messages?

Comment: That's only a piece of the code.  I don't actually see a message it causes a commmand line window to open calling SQLDUMPER.exe and creating a dmp file.  I will edit the original question with the full derived column

Comment: This is failing in Visual Studio/SSDT right? If you deploy it to the server, assuming project deployment model, does it run there or at least run long enough to generate log messages? If package deployment model, run it from the command line `dtexec.exe /file MyPackage.dtsx"

Comment: It's failing in both Visual Studio and running as a JOB in SQL Server where the only message produced in 'The Package Failed'.  I just tried running from the command line and The same thing happens it runs to a point and then SQLDUMPER.exe is called and a dump file is created

Comment: Hmmm, this might be a case for MS support. I've never had cause to use the dump files generated by [sqldumper](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917825) but it sounds like a perverse bit of fun. I'm trying to guess whether it's some weird memory error for your really long expression. While you're not looking to rewrite it, what if you did all this concatenation in a Script Component (as a Transformation)? I can only assume it's going to be less painful than what you have here. Or, if you have lots of these in a single derived column, separate to multiple derived column components.

Comment: Yeah the name SQLDUMPER.exe kinda scared me thinking I had a virus for a second.

Comment: It's possible it a memory error created since SP2 but before that this has run for weeks with no issue. EDIT:  I do not believe it's a memory issues as I shrunk the size of the derived column to just one variable and still received the error I then tried (DT_NTEXT)"1" and the script still crashed

Comment: None of my SSIS packages with Script tasks/transformations work after SP2 - I've currently had to go back to pre SP2 while we sort out a workaround. No change to any package. Can't open the the script designer in in SSDT-BI once Sp2 is installed either. @TimBrown - what is the MS Connect link please. I'd like to add my vote to this issue.

Comment: for the record, here is the Connect item: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/901313/ssis-fails-with-unexpected-termination-when-using-derived-column-to-cast-dt-ntext-to-dt-text-1252

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same problem with a derived column with (DT_NTEXT)"". The workaround I used was a derived column with (DT_WSTR,1)"" followed by a Data Conversion transform which converts to DT_NTEXT. I was then copying XML from a variable to the empty column using a script task and the AddBlobData function. You might be able to use some thing similar to add your type casts.